# Is there any way to perform faster this operation?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, replace

I am dealing with a large medical dataset, and I want to see if there are some rows that corresponds to the same patient. The column that corresponds to the patient's ID is `ID Patient`.
I want to create a new column where it will be `"yes"` if that patient appears in more than one row, or `"no"` if it only appears once.
This is the code that I did:

```
df['Repeated'] = 'No' # New Column

for i in range(0,len(df)):
    for f in range(0,len(df)):
        if df['ID NP'].iloc[i] == df['ID NP'].iloc[f]:
            df['ID NP'].iloc[i] = 'Yes'
        else:
            df['ID NP'].iloc[i] = 'No'
```

However this operation is taking too much time. Is there any way to do it faster?

Comment: You could use [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only does it take too much time, it also sets all `iloc`s to "Yes" in all rows.

You only need to count how many times different ilocs can be found. So count them:

```py
stats = {}
for i in df['ID NP'].iloc:
    stats[i] = stats.get(i, 0) + 1
```

Now you only need to iterate through iloc indices:

```
for i in range(0, len(df['ID NP'].iloc)):
    id_np = df['ID NP'].iloc[i]
    if stats[id_np] > 1:
        # then there should be 'Yes' in this row
```